# If "Undefined", do this, else, do that with arrays and .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, image

I've actually ran out of ideas. I probably have sloppy code here, but it works, until it's missing an array which is returning `undefined`. I've tried the following:

```
if( typeof myVar == "undefined"){}
if(myVar === "undefined"){}
if(myVar != undefined){}
```

-- basically, most things to my knowledge.

Now, I know how to catch an undefined or null object normally, but this is frustrating me.

When one of the arrays returns undefined, it's saying:

`GET http://127.0.0.1:2368/undefined/ 404 (Not Found)`

### Here's the JS:

```
var postImage = $(".post-image");

var imageURL = 
    $('.post-image img').map(function () {
        return this.src;
    });

var i = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < imageURL.length; i++) {

    postImage.each(function () {
        $(this).append('<div class="fetch-image" style="background-image:url(' + imageURL[i++] + ')">');
        $(".post-image img").remove();
    });
}
```

### So the question is...

I want to be able to replace the `/undefined/` URL with a fallback `backgroundImage`, in case no image was set in the first place. The image `src` is only collected if an image is there (obviously), but in case there is no image to get the `src`, I want to be able to set a fallback, **that replaces the missing or `undefined` array.**

Hope this makes sense!

Many regards,

James.

**EDIT**: I've tried the following, inside and outside the `each()` scope:

```
if (typeof imageURL === "undefined") {
    alert("something is undefined");
}
```

I must be missing something here.

Comment: Why not generate broken url at first place?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting an undefined object property in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the things you tried are wrong...

```
if( typeof someVariable == "undefined")
```

Comment: Sorry, I'll update my post. I have attempted this, typo errors! Thank you.

Comment: That's not true. He did compare to `undefined` which should work. The only advantage `typeof` has is that it does not throw an error if the variable hasn't been defined. But I think that's a dubious advantage.

Comment: @lwburk That wasn't in the question before it was edited ;) Only a typoed `typeOf` and two different comparisons against the string `"undefined"`.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop includes:

```
imageURL[i++]
```

This will increment the value of `i` twice with each iteration. Thus, the loop will continue even though the index on the last iteration will out of the array's bounds.

Your array sub index should just be set to just `i` (`imageURL[i]`), and set the third `for` parameter to `i+=2`. The loop should then not return `undefined` values (since `i` will always be within the bounds of the array).

Comment: I *think* this is the right answer, but it's not a very good question. Anyway, +1 because this smells dirty at the least.

Comment: Although I had to sit and think about this a little after I submitted the answer. The bounds of the array will still all be valid, because he's using a post-increment operator within the index. His loop structure should still work (it will just skip some indexes). But I am still leaning toward fixing the loop and/or array structure instead of throwing in a band-aid for `undefined`.

Comment: It's still not known to me why he's doubly incrementing either.

Comment: It's just a poorly asked question. Probably not worth thinking too much about, unfortunately.

Comment: It's the questions that *seem* the easiest that rattle around in your brain the most unfortunately :)